# Designing a pseudo-Doppler transmitter

Tags: rf, antenna, microwave

I am thinking about creating a CW transmitter based on the pseudo-Doppler effect (educational purposes, nothing special in mind). For this purpose, \$n\$ antennas will be placed in a straight line, separated by a distance \$d\$ between them. They will be fed with a coax (all of the \$n\$ coaxes of the same length) to an antenna switch. They all transmit a CW of frequency \$f\$.

In this way, it will be possible to sequentially switch on each of the antennas, creating the effect of an approaching transmitter when seen parallel to the linear agreggation of antennas.

For the switching delay, imagine that we want to achieve a Doppler shift of \$f_d\$. Then,

$$f_d = \frac{2v}{\lambda} = \frac{2vf}{c} = \frac{2fd}{c\tau}$$

It seems that, once we have fixed both the desired \$f_d\$ and the transmitting frequency \$f\$, the next step would be choosing \$d\$. However, I am completely lost here. It seems to me that, if too large \$d\$ is chosen, it will not create the pseudo-Doppler effect well enough. On the other hand, small \$d\$ leads to a huge value for \$n\$ for good transmissions.

Any help will be welcomed!

Comment: The Doppler effect doesn't work that way. You need relative motion to change the distance between wavefronts.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Hence the term pseudo-Doppler. It **does** work, and can be used for receiving, too. Some VHF direction-finding equipment does it this way. I assume you understand the relationship between frequency modulation and phase modulation.

Comment: @DaveTweed How can that possibly work though? It would need to be generating new frequencies by interferring/summing signals of just a single original frequency. Or is it doing something else?

Comment: To the OP: Everything you say is true, but you have neglected to ask an actual question. You're going to have to establish what is acceptable performance for your system and that will then tell you the acceptable value of d. Perhaps try a few examples in simulation.

Comment: @DKNguyen: The "new frequencies" are generated during the crossover from one antenna to the next, when you're effectively summing two signals that have different phases and varying amplitudes.

Comment: @DaveTweed But summing a sinusoid with a phase shifted version of itself still gives a sinusoid of the same frequency, no? UPDATE: Reading it seems it is more about locating/chasing the wavefront than frequency shifting. So Doppler in the sense of the moving part rather than frequency shift part (which is what I think of first when I see Doppler effect)

Comment: Agreed with @DaveTweed, there's a lot missing here. What are you transmitting? What's your symbol rate? How much frequency shift are you trying to create using "pseudo-doppler" and what's your center frequency? What's the receiver? Given that you can *start* to formulate some requirements, and given those, maybe you can make a decision on antennas :)

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you for your comment! Nevertheless, how can I measure performance in this experiment? Or, in other words, what aspects of the CW transmission would degrade by increasing $d$?

Comment: I have no idea. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?